# Excel - lookup data in one worksheet and create a new Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with the following data:

```
Column A  |  Column B  |  Column C - E     |   Column F
==========|============|===================|============
Customer  |  Amount    |  Additional data  |  Paid (Y/N)
```

I would like to create a new worksheet with just the customers who haven't paid and the data from that row.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. We are not here to do your job for you but rather to help you do your job. I suggest you try to solve you issues and then edit your question if/when you run into problems. I would suggest you use a VLOOKUP() formula and a helper sheet to solve your issue, when ready come back and ask for help, provide sample data, your expected results and what you have tried. You will then get help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **Pivot Table**.

- Simply select your data (headers included), then in the ribbon, click on `Insert > Pivot Table`.
- Excel will create a new sheet and a pivot table, that you need to configure. Simply drag the relevant fields in the rows/columns space, and drag the field `Paid` in the filters space.
- Finally, filter the pivot table and select `N`, to display only people who didn't pay.

---

When you add/remove data, don't forget to update the pivot table:

- By right-clicking the pivot table and selecting `Refresh`
- In the ribbon, in the Data tab, by clicking `Refresh All`

---

[More information for setting up and using Pivot Tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter:

1. Select your entire table.
2. Click `Filter` on the Data ribbon.
3. Set the filter on column F by clicking the drop-down triangle button in the column header. Make sure only "No" is checked and then click OK. This will show you all the rows in your table where the Paid value is "No".

To turn off the filter, you can either reset the filter on column F (i.e., make it show all values again, not just "No"), or you can click the `Filter` button in the Data ribbon again to remove the filter altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Try this arrary formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$8="N",ROW(Sheet2!$2:$8)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

[image]